# 22.04 wayland-specific mouse and system lag

Tags: mouse, 22.04, freeze, wayland

Since upgrading to 22.04 I often get periods of unresponsiveness after waking from display sleep - the mouse is jerky and it takes maybe 5-10 seconds to recover.

This is Wayland specific since logging into Xorg solves it... but back to the bad screen tearing I suffered from before (tried the various intel fixes with various success.)

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Seems to be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1982560 (at least similar)?